# How to Pull Data From S3 From Within a Local Docker Container

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I have data currently stored in an s3 bucket that I don't want to be public. I'm attempting to pandas.read_csv("s3_file_path") to load a pandas DataFrame in a script that runs in a docker container. I get a permission denied error. How do I pull the dataframe while giving aws the permissions it wants?

The end goal of this project is the create a RestApi that will process and use a statistical model on some data and return the results. I am also open to a completely different approach that avoids this problem altogether.

As I am the only user of this aws account, just to get it working, I tried putting my aws keys directly in the Dockerfile and running 'aws configure' to essentially copy the exact process I would use if I was doing this without docker. Obviously that is insecure, but I was simply trying to get it to work before I started implementing anything more complex. Unfortunately, it didn't.

Current Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ARG AWS_KEY=My_Actual_Public_Key_In_Plain_Text
ARG AWS_SECRET_KEY=My_Actual_Secret_Key_In_Plain_Text
ARG AWS_REGION='us-east-1'

RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_KEY \
&& aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_KEY \
&& aws configure set default.region $AWS_REGION


COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

run.py

```py
from module import app

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port = 80, debug = True)
```

from **init**.py in module

```py
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_name =  "s3://foo/bar.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

@app.route("/")
def index():

    return("Hello World!")
```

The error I get is:

PermissionError: Access Denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have `s3fs` installed as per the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html). Adding a `print` for debug:

```py
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_name =  "s3://foo/bar.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
print(df)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return("Hello World!")
```

[image]

Ref. the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/): "The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time" - in this case you need the credentials to be available during the runtime, not during the build, you can pass them in the containers runtime environment for example:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV AWS_REGION='us-east-1'

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["flask"]
CMD ["run"]
```

Build the image: `docker build --rm -t so:57700120 .`
Run the container: `docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=... so:57700120`

[image]

**Note**: `boto` does not recognize `AWS_KEY` / `AWS_SECRET_KEY` ref. the [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#environment-variables) for additional information concerning the environment variables which are recognized.